# How to Get List All Classes and Methods from HMVC Codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, hmvc

I have some `modules` in my `HMVC`, is it possible to get lists all `classes` and `methods` in the `modules` directory and put to an array?

Thank You and sorry for my bad English

Comment: no there is no such thing you've to write your own crawler ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. make a library with a name of "Controllerslist" and copy this code ..

```
class Controllerslist {


    private $CI;


    private $aControllers;


    function __construct() {

        $this->CI = get_instance();

        $this->setControllers();
    }


    public function getControllers() {
        return $this->aControllers;
    }


    public function setControllerMethods($p_sControllerName, $p_aControllerMethods) {
        $this->aControllers[$p_sControllerName] = $p_aControllerMethods;
    }

    private function setControllers() {

        foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'modules/controllers/*') as $controller) {


            if(is_dir($controller)) {

                $dirname = basename($controller);


                foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'modules/controllers/'.$dirname.'/*') as $subdircontroller) {

                    $subdircontrollername = basename($subdircontroller, EXT);


                    if(!class_exists($subdircontrollername)) {
                        $this->CI->load->file($subdircontroller);
                    }

                    $aMethods = get_class_methods($subdircontrollername);
                    $aUserMethods = array();
                    foreach($aMethods as $method) {
                        if($method != '__construct' && $method != 'get_instance' && $method != $subdircontrollername) {
                            $aUserMethods[] = $method;
                        }
                    }
                    $this->setControllerMethods($subdircontrollername, $aUserMethods);                                      
                }
            }
            else if(pathinfo($controller, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "php"){

                $controllername = basename($controller, EXT);


                if(!class_exists($controllername)) {
                    $this->CI->load->file($controller);
                }


                $aMethods = get_class_methods($controllername);
                $aUserMethods = array();
                if(is_array($aMethods)){
                    foreach($aMethods as $method) {
                        if($method != '__construct' && $method != 'get_instance' && $method != $controllername) {
                            $aUserMethods[] = $method;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $this->setControllerMethods($controllername, $aUserMethods);                                
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

after this.. in your controller load this library

```
$this->load->library('Controllerslist');
$list = $this->controllerslist->getControllers();
print_r($list);
```

This works for me ..

Comment: why i got NULL result sir ?

Comment: foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'modules/controllers/*')  that APPPATH.'modules/controllers' is correct or not you have to modify as per your folder in HMVC Codeigniter

Comment: Please check your path because its works for me .. my path is APPPATH.'modules/mysite/controllers/'. and its works for me.. can I see your application folder structure .. in which folder you have your controllers ??

Comment: solved sir, i've created my own function .. i think this library cannot read same class declared ...

Comment: If my answers helps you, than will you please upvote my answer ??

Comment: @UtkarshTiwari 15 reputation are needed to be able to upvote, so OP can't do it yet.

Comment: Ok,, thanks @ModusTollens, actually I'm new on Stackoverflow, So I don't know about this, thanks to educate me

Answer (score -1):

small update Utkarsh Tiwari
For HMVC structure we should get all modules list first then all controllers of each modules ..

```
class ControllerList {
      // Codeigniter reference 
    private $CI;

     // Array that will hold the controller names and methods
    private $aControllers;

    // Construct
    function __construct() {
        // Get Codeigniter instance 
        $this->CI = get_instance();

        // Get all controllers 
        $this->setControllers();

    }

    /**
     * Return all controllers and their methods
     * return array
     */
    public function getControllers() {
        return $this->aControllers;
    }

    /**
     * Set the array holding the controller name and methods
     */
    public function setControllerMethods($p_sControllerName, $p_aControllerMethods) {
         $this->aControllers[$p_sControllerName] = $p_aControllerMethods;
    }

    /**
     * Search and set controller and methods.
     */
    private function setControllers() {

        foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'modules/*') as $modules_all) {

            if(is_dir($modules_all)) {

                $dirname = basename($modules_all);

            foreach(glob(APPPATH . 'modules/'.$dirname.'/controllers/*') as $subdircontroller) {

                    $subdircontrollername = basename($subdircontroller, EXT);


                    if(!class_exists($subdircontrollername)) {
                        $this->CI->load->file($subdircontroller);
                    }

                    $aMethods = get_class_methods($subdircontrollername);
                    $aUserMethods = array();
                    foreach($aMethods as $method) {
                        if($method != '__construct' && $method != 'get_instance' && $method != $subdircontrollername) {
                            $aUserMethods[] = $method;
                        }
                    }
                    $this->setControllerMethods($subdircontrollername, $aUserMethods);                                      
                 }
            }
            else if(pathinfo($controller, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "php"){

                $controllername = basename($controller, EXT);


                if(!class_exists($controllername)) {
                    $this->CI->load->file($controller);
                }


                $aMethods = get_class_methods($controllername);
                $aUserMethods = array();
                if(is_array($aMethods)){
                    foreach($aMethods as $method) {
                        if($method != '__construct' && $method != 'get_instance' && $method != $controllername) {
                            $aUserMethods[] = $method;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $this->setControllerMethods($controllername, $aUserMethods);                                
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

after this you can simply get all list of methods and controllers..

```
$this->load->library('controllerlist');
$list = $this->controllerlist->getControllers();
print_r($list);
```

this works for me..